# My first ASF Maven commit -- don't understand the maintainer

Tags: java

I created my first commit for ASF Maven today. In the PR I was asked two things.
By the way: "understand" doesn't mean I speak another language. It is more about his and my opinions and arguments.

### Else-If instead of guard statements / early return

So, there is no documentation and no check style rule that says this, but the maintainer does.

Given this code I created:

```java
  protected void setColumn( /* Nullable */ String column )
  {
    if ( null == column || column.length() < 1 )
     {
      this.column = NO_COLUMN;
      return;
     }

    this.column = column;
  }
```

They want me to change it to:

```java
  protected void setColumn( /* Nullable */ String column )
  {
    if ( null == column || column.length() < 1 )
    {
      this.column = NO_COLUMN;
     }
     else
     {
       this.column = column;
     }
  }
```

I always thought this code style(2nd one) is an anti-pattern. Why? Because:

1. If more conditions appear, you can keep track of the actual "standard" case.
2. It will invite to use more nesting
3. It is less clear which part the main code is, because there is no unnested code.

In fact, at work, we do not use `else` ever. For every 50.000 loc, there is about 2-3 else statements at most. We are very happy with it.

At most, I consider this a cosmetic change.

Still, I can see why they want this -- this is how they code, although it is not written down. Is there any advantage of this I am missing? I (myself) consider this MUCH less readable than a guard statement. They even called it uncommon. Is this really true??

### Return modifiable collections

Given my code:

```java
List<FooObject> foo = new ArrayList();

for // doing foo or bar, adding foo.put(new FooObject())

return Collections.unmodifiableList( foo );
```

They want me to change it to:

```java
return foo;
```

I can see why they want this. The `List` interface was an error in Java 1.1. It is surprising that an available method will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Unless you are VERY used to unmodifiable collections.

Anyway, I always considered modifying lists which your method did not create yourself an anti-pattern.
You never know where it is used elsewhere, and modifiable collections embrace race conditions, concurrent modifications or even other bugs. Imagine you print the list of FooObject, and another commit will add some `foo.removeIf()` statements in some other unrelated method later. The print method will be incomplete, and it might be really hard to track down.

Most bugs I saw in real life code was due to modified collections. In my experience, `UnsupportedOperationExceptions` are spotted easily. On the other hand, it might be hard to track down whether a collection was modified in some curious instance or not.

But with the code known and completely in "our" hands, I also consider this more or less a cosmetic change.

### Do *I* need to change this?

I expect the maintainer to do cosmetic changes. Is this a valid expectation? On the other hand, I do not want to be responsible for the above mentioned exception cases (elements missing from a list, concurrent modification exceptions, lots of nested `if`s and `else if`s…).

If not because of the mentioned reasons, then because those "rules" are nowhere mentioned. The argument is "the community opinion". Well, as a first time committer, you do not know "the" community opinion if it is not written down.

But maybe working with colleagues burned my head. *I really want to review myself here.*

By the way: I am not talking about other code styles / conventions (like: where to put an opening brace, where to put a space). They have strict rules, and I really love having strict rules, even if I would have chosen other rules.

This question only applies to code which is valid by the `checkstyle` definition and comes down (mostly) to cosmetic changes and/or personal habits and preferences.

### Is it worth it?

If I gave in, contrary to my (current! change it!) opinion and beliefs, could I be "responsible" in any case? I mean, imagine some of the scenarios I mentioned would be happing -- would someone track me down with a blame function? Is it the better way to let others change my code in a github review?

---

In any way, thanks for looking into this. My only goal is to create good pull requests for open source projects. I created the commits to my best understanding, and I love good arguments. So far, the unwritten "community opinion" and "most code I saw" are the best arguments I saw from the maintainer. My impression and experience is, that my current code would be preferable and more maintainable.

How do I "know" who is right? Is there a "right" or "wrong" next to "the maintainer is always right"? Is it worth discussing with a maintainer?

Comment: I created another PR where you can see how a forced else will (in my opinion) created unnecessary indentation changes: https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/pull/58

Comment: This question is explicitly soliciting opinions around conventions. As such it is not asking for a review. In addition all of the code presented here is not reviewable, because it's lacking all overarching context. Therefore I have closed this question as off-topic. For more information, see [meta] and the [help/on-topic]. Thanks!

Comment: As a personal opinion of an OSS maintainer: If in doubt use the rule of thumb "In rome, do as the romans do". It's easier to maintain a codebase that uses a consistent set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

> Else-If instead of guard statements / early return

Where I am we do the same thing as what the maintainer is suggesting.

IMHO you are way over thinking it and it does not matter. The only thing that matters is **consistency**. You're obviously used to doing it the first way, which makes the second seem so unnatural. Don't take it personally, you get used to following the code base's style as you practice committing to different projects.

It's unfortunate they don't have a style guide or anything. But it doesn't mean anything goes.

> They even called it uncommon. Is this really true

It's probably uncommon in their code base. Either way it really doesn't matter which is more popular.

> Is there any advantage of this I am missing

No, I'd bet it compiles to the same byte code. You could check.

> Return modifiable collections

As someone whose also dealt with hard-to-find bugs relating to lists being mutable, I agree with what you said. But from the maintainers point of view, the code base should be changed entirely to follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Else-if etc.**

Well, you often find the requirement "single return" in coding standards. Whether you like it or not, don't put any deeper meaning to it. This is just the same as I'd say "fix your formatting" (:-)) if it was my project. The only life lesson here is, that in 95% of a developer's work you will not be able to define the standard, and just have to follow. Just deal with it.

**List return**

As far as I understand your code, you specifically create a list locally in a method just to return it. So, there is no outer scope involved, no external "ownership" for the collection, nothing of that sort. Therefore, restricting the possible operations on the return value, which you created specifically for the caller, makes no sense. (Your best practices probably stem from the returning of internal object values - there, I absolutely agree with you.)

Furthermore, there also is a standard in the given project: if every method returns a modifiable collection, the user will expect this. Having a *single* method in the middle of the project wich behaves differently will stick out like a sore thumb.

What I *personally* would do is, to document the concrete return value in the method signature. So, instead of returning a generic `List` (aka I don't tell you whether you can modify the list, I don't tell you whether you can index-access the list, etc.) I'd return an `ArrayList`. (Principle behind this: always demand the smallest contract possible in your parameters, and return the biggest contract you can afford.) (And let's face it: all this "you can change the implementation later" that everyone tells you is pure B.S. - it is *never* done in practice.) - But probably that would lead to conflicts with the maintainer again.

Bottom line: that's life in software. There's no personal fault on your side, and no personal fault in the maintainer's views either. Different projects have different approaches, and as a programmer, you have to learn to adapt.

And regarding the changes and ownership: do it yourself. Take responsibility for your code, your logic, and your reasoning behind it, even *if* you have to adhere to a standard to get it accepted.